# Set format of date pulled from Google Sheets to webapp

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, date-formatting

I do not have any coding knowledge and have only been publishing sites/webapp by copying off of youtube tutorials.
This is the sample of the code I got from one of the channels, and I formatted it to my desired display/interface and successfully pulled data from my google sheets.

```html
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html')
    .setTitle("LPO Transaction Tracker");
}
function submitDT(obj){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("google sheet url");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mysheet");
  var  flag  =  1 ;
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
      for(var i = 1;i <= lr;i++){
  var vid = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      if(vid ==obj){
      flag = 0;
  var b1 = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();      
  var b3 = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
  var b4 = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
  var b5 = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
  var b6 = sheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
  var b7 = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
  var b8 = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();

  
  var data ="<center><table><tr><th colspan=2>Transaction Information.</th></tr><tr><td>Tracking No.:</td><td>"
+obj+"</td></tr><tr><td>Transaction Title</td><td>"+b1+"</td></tr><tr><td>Date Accepted by Focal:</td><td>"+b3+"</td></tr><tr><td>Name of Establishment:</td><td>"+b4+"</td></tr><tr><td>Address:</td><td>"+b5+"</td></tr><tr><td>Status:</td><td>"+b6+"</td></tr><tr><td>Claimed by:</td><td>"+b7+"</td></tr><tr><td>Date Claimed:</td><td>"+b8+"</td></tr></table></center>";
  return data;
    }
   }
     if(flag==1){
  var data ="Transaction not found. For other concerns, please contact us at **********";
      return data;
    } 
    };
```

However, my problem is I do not know how to format the date from the "getvalue" for b3 and b8. When the webapp is executed the date format is as shown in the image below. However, I only need for "dd MMMM yyyy" format to be displayed

[enter image description here][1]

I've searched and browsed the net for hours already but I just couldn't find the proper code for it. I hope you guys can help me out. Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTTLK.png

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Utilities.formatDate

You can format your date as a string using [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)). For example, for `b3`:

```
b3 = Utilities.formatDate(b3, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd MMMM yyyy");
```

#### Option 2: getDisplayValues

If your desired format is the one currently displayed on the spreadsheet, you can use [Range.getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) instead of `getValue` to retrieve a string formatted the way it is displayed, instead of a date:

```
var b3 = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getDisplayValue();
```

#### Note:

For greater efficiency, instead of retrieving each cell value individually via `getValue`, get the full range of cells you want to retrieve and get all its values at once via [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). For example, you could get all your data at once via:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, lr, 8).getValues();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Option 2 worked like magic! I didn't try option 1 at all since I am not sure where to put the code at all. And thank you for giving the note, I'll try and read it when I have an available time. <3